# MS Sql Server on Fedora 34 failing with status 127

Tags: sql, sql-server, fedora, systemctl

I'm recently moved to fedora 34 and trying to install MS Sql Server, but it isn't starting.
Installation is clean, setup is done by running

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup
```

status check

```
sudo systemctl status mssql-server
```

returns this

```
mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
 Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-08-30 18:51:56 EEST; 11min ago
   Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux
Process: 1027 ExecStart=/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr (code=exited, status=127)
```

logs say:

```
Aug 30 18:51:55 fedora systemd[1]: Started Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
Aug 30 18:51:55 fedora sqlservr[933]: /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: error while loading shared libraries: libldap-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or >
Aug 30 18:51:55 fedora systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Aug 30 18:51:55 fedora systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 30 18:51:55 fedora systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Aug 30 18:51:55 fedora systemd[1]: Stopped Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
```

(and same 3 times)

How do i fix this? I really love fedora look and feel and don't want to give up on it, because one my work tools isn't working.

Comment: BTW libldap, mentioned in logs seems to be some kind of bluetooth sound codec/helper.
How it's even possible for it to mess up with database server startup?

Comment: more likely it's LDAP: Lightweight Directory Access Protocol which would make more sense than bluetooth

Comment: i tried to reinstall openldap, but it makes no difference

Answer (score 5):

```
dnf install openldap-compat
```

helped

for more info you can run

```
rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2
```

or similar

Comment: Alternatively, `dnf repo-query --whatprovides ...` to find pacakges for a file you don't have installed.